# Accessing information from mysql query results array?

Tags: php, mysql

I looked at the official documentation,but I still can't seem to access the independent    variables for example "city". After a sql query, I use   $results[0] to get this. How can I access "city"?

```
   $results =  DB::table('users')->get();

    birthdate = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    city = "Laguna Hills";
    country = "<null>";
    "created_at" = "2014-07-21 07:11:06";
    email = "sammy0@gmail.com";
    id = 1;
    "is_verified" = "<null>";
    "location_lat" = "<null>";
    "location_lon" = "<null>";
    password = RightNow25;
    "updated_at" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    username = sammy0;
    zip = "<null>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the full output to the page using 'print_r' (see the below code). It is very useful since you can see all elements within the array along with they keys and values.

```
//(using print_r between '<pre>' and '</pre>' formats the data to a human readable format)


print '<pre>';
print_r($results);
print '</pre>';
```

This should help to identify if your data is being returns as intended.